# I am trying to force a script to accept user input, but it breaks on the second input

Tags: string, powershell, input, directory

I am new to Power shell and I cant seem to wrap my head around this one.

The Code works when you take the input out and place actual values in for each $number and $Name as seen in the bottom example. I found that unlike specifying the values, line 7 char 13 cant be -$Name but rather has to be $Name. After doing this it tells me ln 15 char 13 "a positional character cannot be found that accepts argument "- "." where the "-" = $Name.

What do I need to change to get this to function? I have tired using [parameter(Mandatory=$true,name='What would you like your folder to be named: ')] but I cant seem to get that to work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$number = read-host "How Many Folders would you like to create: "
$Name = read-host "What would you like your folder to be named: "
$intFolders = $number 
$intPad
$i = 1

New-Variable -$Name strPrefix -Value "$Name" -Option constant

    do {

        if ($i -lt $number)
            {$intPad=0 
                new-item -path c:\mytest -$Name $strPrefix$intPad$i -type directory}
        else
            {new-item -path c:\mytest -$Name $strPrefix$i -type directory}
            $i++}
        until ($i -eq $intFolders+1)
```

This is the code below that I was able to get to work, but I want to make sure when I am gone people here can still use it for their needs as they do not understand coding.

```
$intFolders = 500
$intPad
$i = 1

New-Variable -Name strPrefix -Value "0001_" -Option constant

    do {

        if ($i -lt 500)
            {$intPad=0 
                new-item -path c:\mytest -name $strPrefix$intPad$i -type directory}
        else
            {new-item -path c:\mytest -name $strPrefix$i -type directory}
            $i++}
        until ($i -eq $intFolders+1)
```

Thanks to Bruce here is the working Final code that does excatly what it should have :)

```
[int]$start = read-host "What number would you like your folder to start at"
[int]$number = read-host "How Many Folders would you like to create"
$Name = read-host "What would you like your folder to be named"
$intFolders = $number 
$intPad
$i = $start

New-Variable -Name strPrefix -Value "$Name" -Option constant

    do {

        if ($i -lt 10)
            {$intPad="" 
                new-item -path c:\mytest -Name $strPrefix$intPad$i -type directory}
        else
            {new-item -path c:\mytest -Name $strPrefix$i -type directory}
            $i++}
        until ($i -eq $intFolders+1)
```

Comment: [PowerShell will add the colon to the end of the prompt for you](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176935.aspx), and [Don't use Hungarian Notation](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/what-do-not-do-powershell-part-5)

Comment: Thank you BobLobLaw, I was unaware of that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
New-Variable -$Name strPrefix -Value "$Name" -Option constant
```

to

```
New-Variable -Name strPrefix -Value "$Name" -Option constant
```

Same for the -$name in the new-item lines.  See Get-Help New-Variable and Get-Help New-Item.

Comment: Thank you, that works like a charm but it adds a extra 0. for instance. I tell it to create 1 folder, it creates 10, I tell it to create 1,000 it creates 10,000.

Comment: Change your first line to [int]$number = read-host "How Many Folders would you like to create: "  Also, I think you may want to change the IF condition to "if ($i -lt 10) " to get the pad character.

Comment: Bruce, Thank you once again! It now works like a champ! I will add the final code to the above.